# is this efficient MYSQL Query?

Tags: mysql

I'm using vbulletin 5 and getting message from the host that MYSQL Query was killed because it was running over 1 minutes .. I looked at the query and feel there is something wrong with it .. though I don't have enough experience to judge 
here is the query ..

```
SELECT DISTINCT node.starter AS nodeid
  FROM node as node
    JOIN closure AS closure ON node.nodeid = closure.child 
    LEFT JOIN node AS starter 
      ON starter.nodeid = IF(node.starter = 0, node.nodeid, node.starter)

  WHERE node.contenttypeid <> 19 
    AND node.contenttypeid IN ('22','26','23','21','20','25') 
    AND closure.parent = '2' 
    AND node.nodeid <> closure.parent 
    AND node.contenttypeid <> '15' 
    AND node.userid <> '28030'
    AND (node.public_preview = 1 
      OR 
        ( 
          ( 
            ( 
              (
                starter.parentid IN (1,2,3,6,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,247197,257065,7,8,9,12,51,59,62,27,32,33,36,44,45,50,35,34,37,38,39,40,61,60,57,43,42,46,47,28,29,30,31,41,48,49,52,53,54,55,56,58,63,65,64,247199,247200,66) 
              ) 
              AND node.showapproved > 0 
              AND node.viewperms > 1 
              AND node.showpublished > 0 
            )
          )
        OR starter.parentid = 9 AND node.userid IN (0)
      )
    )

  ORDER BY node.lastcontent DESC,node.nodeid ASC
  LIMIT 500
```

Comment: LEFT JOINing a table from which you select no columns doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

Comment: thank you , any suggestions for optimized query ?

Comment: in addition you have this ... `node.contenttypeid <> 19 AND 
node.contenttypeid IN ('22','26','23','21','20','25') AND node.contenttypeid <> '15'` does this sum up to simply `node.contenttypeid NOT IN (15,19)`

Comment: @Strawberry the joined tables are used in the where clause.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy Yes - but in an OR clause, which makes it a bit murky

Comment: Whenever I see `DISTINCT` I think that there is a better way with `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte It's unfortunate that MySQL is better able to optimise GROUP BY than DISTINCT, because substituting one for the other is often erroneous.

Comment: My over-riding suspicion is that a system warranting such a convoluted query is poorly designed - but I may well be mistaken.

Comment: I reformatted the query a bit to be mostly readable without scrolling, the one bit that extends past the edge is just the remainder of the IN list. But you can see that there are quire a few extra parenthesis in there which could be removed. One pattern you have is `(A or (((B)) or C))` which could be refactored to `(A or B or C)` even expression `B` looks a bit odd as it is `(a) and b and c and d` which should be more like `(a and b and c and d)`.